# Table does not exists error in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an inheritance relationship in my program as Car and Van extends Vehicle. In my case it is a mandatory participation therefore if a vehicle exists it must be a car or a van. Therefore I am using only two tables(car & van) which have columns for super class and subclass fields.

```
public class Vehicle {

    protected int vin;
    protected String brand;

    public Vehicle(){}

    public Vehicle(int vin, String brand) {
        this.vin = vin;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public int getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

    public void setVin(int vin) {
        this.vin = vin;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
```

Car.java

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private String model;

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Car(){

    }

    public Car(int vin, String brand, String model) {
        this.vin = vin;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
    }
```

Van.java

```
public class Van extends Vehicle {

private String vanModel;

public Van(){}

public Van(int vin,String brand,String vanModel) {
    this.vanModel = vanModel;
    this.vin=vin;
    this.brand=brand;
}

public String getVanModel() {
    return vanModel;
}

public void setVanModel(String vanModel) {
    this.vanModel = vanModel;
}
```

Mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Vehicle">
    <id name="vin" type="int" column="vin">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>

    <property name="brand" column="brand"/>

    <union-subclass name="Car" table="car">
        <property name="model" column="model"/>
    </union-subclass>

    <union-subclass name="Van" table="van">
        <property name="vanModel" column="vanmodel"/>
    </union-subclass>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to insert anything to car or van table the following error comes. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myjdbc.vehicle' doesn't exist. I have no idea about this. I never mentioned a table name as vehicle. So why am I getting this error? As I am quite new to hibernate please give me a detailed answer.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html check this, as per the document you need to have 3 tables . see section 9.1.5

Answer (score 1):

assumming there's no such thing as a concrete vehicle, define the vehicle class to be abstract and make it a [mappedSuperclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/MappedSuperclass.html).

there's an example of doing this in hbm.xml [here](http://gardiary.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/hibernate-superclass-interface-inheritance-mapping/)